# What is the code to hide/show a button in Adobe PDF when clicking another button that's purpose is to shows/hides a layer?

Tags: javascript, pdf, button, show-hide

I have a button that I edited the action to "run a JavaScript" under "Mouse Down."

This is the code I put into the JavaScript (Button is titled "Site External Doors"):

```
var docOCGs = this.getOCGs(); 
for (var x=0; x < docOCGs.length; x++) 
{
          if(docOCGs[x].name == "Site External Doors" ||
     docOCGs[x].name == "Site External Doors")
          {
                    docOCGs[x].state = !docOCGs[x].state; 
 }
}
// Button Style and Label Change 
if(event.target.borderStyle == border.b)
{
          // Perform Push Down Actions
          event.target.borderStyle = border.i;

          event.target.buttonSetCaption("Site External Doors Off");
} else {
          // Perform Pop Up Actions

          event.target.borderStyle = border.b;

          event.target.buttonSetCaption("Site External Doors On");
}
```

This code shows a layer when clicked and hides the layer when clicked again.
I am wondering what code I need to add to get another button (titled "Door 52") to appear when the button "Site External Doors" is clicked and hide when it is clicked again.

Answer (score 1):

Acroform buttons, like other fields, have a "display" property you can set. You should be able to set the "Door 52" button to be hidden on creation, then make it visible with code such as:

```
// Show the button
var door52 = getField("Door 52");
door52.display = display.visible;

// Hide the button again
door52.display = display.hidden;
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough! It worked! No more frustration and headaches!